# Only show non blank attributes for a model in views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I've a user model and there are bunch of user info, like email, birthdate, location, telephone number etc.

What's the simplest way of hiding the attributes that are blank?

I've doing something like

```
<% if blog.title.empty? -%>
 <p>Body: <%=h blog.body %></p>
 <p>Comments: <%=h blog.comments %></p>

<% elsif blog.body.empty? %>
 <p>Title: <%=h blog.title %></p>
 <p>Comments: <%=h blog.comments %></p>

<% else -%>
 <p>Title: <%=h blog.title %></p>
 <p>Body: <%=h blog.body %></p>
<% end -%>
```

Clearly that is one ugly child. Other than using partials to render, is there a trick to only show non blank fields?

I've been trying to write a helpher method to make the view cleaner, but that's even more ugly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can not do it using if-else condition. because if your IF condition get true no matter for other ELSIF conditions it not get executed.
for ex:- title & body both are not empty still you can see title only.

Comment: Actually it worked for me. If one thing matched, I wouldn't want the other ones to get executed or I would have three instances of each entry. The entire thing was under for blog in @blogs, so for each example it when step by step, stopping if any returned true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
# blog_helper.rb
show_non_blank_field(label, value)
  "<p>#{label}: #{h value}</p>" if !value.blank?
end
```

and then in view:

```
<%= show_non_blank_field "Body", blog.body %>
```

and so on...

Of course you can use shorter helper name.

If you want to do it in `if-else` way, try this:

```
<% if !blog.title.blank? -%>
 <p>Title: <%=h blog.title %></p>
<% end %>

<% if !blog.body.blank? %>
 <p>Body: <%=h blog.body %></p>
<% end %>

<p>Comments: <%=h blog.comments %></p>
```

Comment: As a slight variation on that theme, you could use "content_tag" (either in the helper or in the view) to remove the embedded HTML, as in something like:

content_tag(:p, "%s: %s" % [label, value]) unless value.blank?

Comment: I didn't know content_tag could be used like that. Thanks. What about sql injection. I assume using %s instead of label or value takes care of that.

Comment: @Senthil: You don't have to care about label as long as it is always typed in views (not from user editable field in db). I don't know if label or value from @NeilS example is escaped, but you always can use `[h(label), h(value)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
show_field_unless_empty(blog, :body, 'Body')
```

then, in blog_helper.rb

```
def show_field_unless_empty(model, field, title)
  render :partial => 'field', :locals => {:value => model.send(field), :title => title} if model.send(field)
end
```

then, in _field.html.erb

```
<p>
<%= title %>: 
<%= value %>
</p>
```

This seems fairly clean to me.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really work. It gives me the same value as before.